# AVPlayer videoGravity AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill doesn't work Swift2.2

Tags: swift

Please help me with AVPlayer. I need resize video when iPhone rotate (landscape orientation). Here is my code:

```
var player: AVPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Load the video from the app bundle.
    let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bg_animate", withExtension: "3gp")!

    player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
    player?.actionAtItemEnd = .None
    player?.muted = true

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = -1
    playerLayer.frame = view.frame
    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player?.play()

    //loop video
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.loopVideo), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
}
```

But string:

```
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

doesnt work.

I also set value as `AVLayerVideoGravityResize` and `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect`, but had similar results...